# Automatically Calculate price jquery/javascript function for form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically I need to add to this form - http://jsfiddle.net/tSsvb/ automatically price calculation. For example the parameters are these - (The 3 bikes are only test, there may be like 100 or even 200).
So basically -

```
Bike 1 -
Price for 1 - 2 days in Season 1 - 5$ per day.
Price for 1 - 2 days in Season 2 - 10$ per day.
Price for 1 - 2 days in Season 3 - 20$ per day.
Price for 3 - 7 days in Season 1 - 4$ per day.
Price for 3 - 7 days in Season 2 - 7$ per day.
Price for 3 - 7 days in Season 3 - 15$ per day.
Price for 8+ days in Season 1 - 3$ per day.
Price for 8+ days in Season 2 - 5$ per day.
Price for 8+ days in Season 3 - 12$ per day.

Bike 2 -
Price for 1 - 2 days in Season 1 - 10$ per day.
Price for 1 - 2 days in Season 2 - 20$ per day.
Price for 1 - 2 days in Season 3 - 30$ per day.
Price for 3 - 7 days in Season 1 - 7$ per day.
Price for 3 - 7 days in Season 2 - 15$ per day.
Price for 3 - 7 days in Season 3 - 25$ per day.
Price for 8+ days in Season 1 - 5$ per day.
Price for 8+ days in Season 2 - 12$ per day.
Price for 8+ days in Season 3 - 22$ per day.

Bike 3 -
Price for 1 - 2 days in Season 1 - 3$ per day.
Price for 1 - 2 days in Season 2 - 5$ per day.
Price for 1 - 2 days in Season 3 - 10$ per day.
Price for 3 - 7 days in Season 1 - 2$ per day.
Price for 3 - 7 days in Season 2 - 3$ per day.
Price for 3 - 7 days in Season 3 - 7$ per day.
Price for 8+ days in Season 1 - 1$ per day.
Price for 8+ days in Season 2 - 2$ per day.
Price for 8+ days in Season 3 - 5$ per day.
```

And the season dates are -

```
Season 1: 1 January to 10 June and 21 September to 31 December
Season 2: 11 June to 30 June and 1 September to 20 September
Season 3: 1 July to 31 August
```

So let's do a test calculation.
If I choose a date from 1st July to 25 September the calculation will be for bike 3 as following -

62*5 + 20*2 + 5*1 = 310 + 40 + 5 = 355$

And this sum should automatically add in text field "Price". If I change the dates, the price should automatically change too. Is there any easy way to create something like that? If you have any questions - ask, I will be happy to answer to them, so you can help me solve this question more easily.

Comment: EDIT: I have a hardcoded version of this, but it doesn't work too well, and it has about 2000 rows of code, so I would like to make it shorter and more comfortable for other programmer who will later use it.

Comment: Oh and prices will be passed with PHP.

Comment: If you calculate the right price with PhP you only have to use an Ajax call and inject it in the input price. Are you looking for an example of Jquery ajax call? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I'm lazy, and really not willing to keep scrolling up and down to read relevant sections of the question, so can you explain where the numbers in your example calculation come from.

Comment: Do you mean the 62*5 + 20*2 + 5*1 = 310 + 40 + 5 = 355$ ? It comes from the Bike 3 and the Season table/Description.

Comment: I would appreciate any help :(.

Comment: You have the last bit of your calc wrong. Its 5 days in season 1 which is `5*2` not `5*1`

Comment: Hmm, no you understood it a little bit wrong :)! If the total days are less than 7 and greater than 2, then it will take the price, but if total days will be more than 8, then it will take one price (8+ price) for all days. So basically, if we will have to tal days 1 or 2, it will take price as 1-2 day price, if it will be > 2 and <= 7 then it will take price as 3 - 7 days. And if it total days will be more than 8 (in this case 87), it will take price for all calculation from 8+ days. In additional, when you have time, please check my reply to your answer ;)! Thank you for helping me :)!

Comment: No, I understood that perfectly, but the final bit of your example calc `5*1` represents 21st-25th September which is in season 1, and is 5 days long. 5 days, in season 1 for bike 3 is $2/day not $1/day. Therefore the final result is $360 not $355.

Comment: Hello, Hehe, no well basically, as I said, the days are taken from total (all days), from start date to end date, so even if there would be like this - 7 days in season 1 and 2 days in season 2, then the price for all calculation should be taken as 8+ days for season 1 and 8+ days for season 2. If the total count of days are 8 or more, then all price calculation will be taken as 8+ days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tSsvb/1/

I started with 2 variables which represent

- an array of the various seasons
- an object which represents the pricing matrix

---

```
var seasonLookup = [
    {startDay: 1, startMonth:1, endDay: 10, endMonth: 6, season:1},
    {startDay: 21, startMonth:9, endDay: 31, endMonth: 12, season:1},
    {startDay: 11, startMonth:6, endDay: 30, endMonth: 6, season:2},
    {startDay: 1, startMonth:9, endDay: 20, endMonth: 9, season:2},
    {startDay: 1, startMonth:7, endDay: 31, endMonth: 8, season:3},    
    ];

var priceMatrix = {
    bike3: {
        1: { t1: 2, t2: 2, t3: 1},
        2: { t1: 5, t2: 3, t3: 2},
        3: { t1: 10, t2: 3, t3: 5}
    }        
};
```

---

The first is pretty straightforward. The second I have only moddled up bike3 as it's the one youve used in your example. `1`,`2` & `3` represent the season, `t1` - `t3` represent the tier's of payment with `t1` hardcoded as 1-2 days, `t2` as 3-7 and `t3` as 8+.

Then I have created 2 functions. One gets the season for a specified date:

```
function getSeason(date){
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth()+1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    for(var i=0;i<seasonLookup.length;i++){
        var s = seasonLookup[i];
        var startDate = new Date(year, s.startMonth-1,s.startDay);
        var endDate = new Date(year, s.endMonth-1,s.endDay);
        if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
            return s.season;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The other gets the total price for a specified bike in a specified season for a specified number of days:

```
function getPrice(bike, season, days){
  var tier = "";
  if(days <=2)
    tier = "t1";
  else if(days <=7)    
      tier = "t2";
   else
       tier = "t3"
   return priceMatrix[bike][season][tier] * days;
}
```

---

Next step is a method to do the actual calculation based on a start date, end date and bike:

```
function calculatePrice(startDate, endDate, bike)
{
   var currentSeason = getSeason(startDate);
   var totalPrice = 0;
   var daysInSeason = 0;
   var currentDate = startDate;
   while(currentDate<=endDate){
       var season = getSeason(currentDate);
       if(season != currentSeason){
              totalPrice += getPrice(bike,currentSeason,daysInSeason);
              currentSeason = season;
              daysInSeason = 0;
       }
       daysInSeason++;
       currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1);        
   }
    totalPrice += getPrice(bike,currentSeason,daysInSeason);
    return totalPrice;
}
```

And the final part is to hook it up so that it recalculates on any change of the dropdowns. jQuery is your friend here. I hadded a class `recalc` to all elements that should cause the recalculation, id's to everything to make them easier to reference, and hooked into the `change` event to build the parameters and call the method:

```
$('.recalc').change(function(){
    var startDate = new Date(parseInt($('#yd').val(),10),parseInt($('#md').val(),10)-1,parseInt($('#dd').val(),10) );
    var endDate = new Date(parseInt($('#yr').val(),10),parseInt($('#mr').val(),10)-1,parseInt($('#dr').val(),10));
    var bike = $('#bike').val();

    var price = calculatePrice(startDate,endDate,bike);
    $('#price').val(price);

});
```

Hope that helps, you may need to generate your pricing matricies from PHP, but thats an excercise for you :)

Comment: Hello, Okay, thanks I will check it and try to add something from my side too. So basically, what I checked is that you have passed the prices in array, but I have them passed via PHP, so any suggestions about that (if I will have more than 200 bikes), I would like them automatically get added dinamically, not to write each tiem in file. About first function, as far as I understood, it takes current date, but what I ment, is that it must take the date from form field "From". Okay that is nothing serious, it can be changed easily. Will try to figure out something too. Again thanks!

Comment: Okay so I understood your idea about the first function. But now the question is if I pass the prices via PHP, how can I easily them add to javascript array PriceMatrix? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, no you understood it a little bit wrong :)! If the total days are less than 7 and greater than 2, then it will take the price, but if total days will be more than 8, then it will take one price (8+ price) for all days. So basically, if we will have to tal days 1 or 2, it will take price as 1-2 day price, if it will be > 2 and <= 7 then it will take price as 3 - 7 days. And if it total days will be more than 8 (in this case 87), it will take price for all calculation from 8+ days. In additional, when you have time, please check my reply to your answer ;)! Thank you for helping me :)!

Comment: Wow, thanks! Maybe you could give me any hints of passing the PHP prices to calculation? I had idea, to take them fro, the option with javascript, like priceone="2" pricetwo="3" ... pricenine="9" e.c., and then input it in array. Would that work? I would add the pricex to each option for bike selection.

Comment: Im going to stop short of trying to help you build up the pricing matrix using PHP. For 1 I dont know PHP, and for 2 you have not given any indication of how it's stored, how you retrieve it etc. If you go ahead and use my method, you just need to make a javascript object which looks like my pricing matrix, or vary my method to read from however you want to build your own from PHP.

Comment: And In additional, currently haven't checked your code at 100%, since I'm not at pc, but viewing from phone, so basically, did you add the calculation correctly? I mean, did you read my comment, about the calculation. 2 Comments above this or the last comment in my post.

Comment: the prices are very simple... put them in a table, create exact same array structure in php, and json_encode to to page as js variable, or do an ajax call to get price based on season&days&bike type

Comment: Okay, I have edited it, so it looks as it would work for me, but the problem is that it doesn't calculate anymore. Could you please take a look at the script? http://jsfiddle.net/tSsvb/2/